# Comparing all the noise reduction filters in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

What I am doing as a part of my project is comparing and analysing all the noise removal and reduction filters there are in matlab.

Not able to find a comprehensive list of filters that have been built for this very purpose.

Well adding to my question, I wanted a list that would help me understand all the basics of noise removal using filters in matlab.

I have found various links such as [this](http://academic.mu.edu/phys/matthysd/web226/L0205.htm), which proved helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the docs for:

http://www.mathworks.com/products/signal/index.html

http://www.mathworks.com/products/statistics/

Loads more at:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/

When you have the toolboxes installed, you can also just look at the table of contents in the "Help" browser.  Gives a pretty good summary of the options.